# How to get all commits from present to a specific tag in gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Assume I have some known tag - "my_tag"

Since that tag, in the current branch - "my branch", there were commits.

I would like a list of all those commits (each containing at least the committer name and the commit message)

How can this be done with gitpython?

How can this be done with plain git?

Answer (score 0):

In plain git you would do something like

```
git log --pretty=format:"%cn %B" my_tag..my_branch
```

`--pretty=format` helps formatting with `%cn` for committer name and `%B` for commit message (subject + body, if any)

The `A..B` range means "everything reachable from B which is NOT reachable from A"

---

I'll let others answer for the gitpython part that I don't know.

Comment: `git log --pretty=format:"%cn %B" Kodex-1.4.7.703..master` This gets everything since the given tag to the tag before it. I want to get everything from the given tag until NOW (no tag necessary).
Also, I would like an explanation

Comment: "everything since the given tag to the tag before it" I don't understand what you mean here. Maybe I misunderstood your general goal : don't you want to get all commits which have been made on this branch since that tag? If you need everything since that tag until now, just omit the second part of the range : `Kodex-1.4.7.703..` , from the relevant branch of course since no ref implies `HEAD`.

Comment: I looked at the commits wrong. This does ALMOST what I want - For some reason, SOMETIMES, it gives all commits since the given tag until now, but it also gives one commit before the `my_tag` commit, instead of the tag's commit itself

Comment: @Gulzar This is unexpected. Hard to tell more without inspecting the repo. Maybe try to update your question with sample log outputs to show what you're getting?